# Jersey: pre- and post-exec hooks?

Tags: java, jersey

I'm currently using aspectj to handle transactions in my Jersey RESTful classes. But I want to dump it for simplicity and consistency reasons (less technologies -> more transparency, better IDE support). I also want the REST get method implementations to return a w3c document class, ie. having a post-exec hooks that transforms results.

Does Jersey provide pre- and post-exec hook that allow me to initiate and close transactions and perform transformations on results returned to the remote end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using version 2.x, Jersey has built in support for this, using [Event Listeners](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#d0e16007). You can use a `RequestEventListener`, and the [`RequestEvent`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.26-b09/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/RequestEvent.html) give you access to all the goodies. Matter of fact, for transaction handling, this is actually the way [Dropwizard handles it](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v1.1.3/dropwizard-hibernate/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/hibernate/UnitOfWorkApplicationListener.java).

If the event handlers doesn't suit your needs, there is more of a "natural" [AOP support from HK2](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/extensibility.html#interception) (which Jersey uses for DI). Check out [this article](https://blog.dejavu.sk/2015/01/21/intercepting-jersey-resource-method-calls/) for a complete example integrating with Jersey.

Comment: and there is the RS interface MessageBodyWriter to support custom return types. cool.